Python-Polars: Performance of wide dataframe
We are currently implementing a calculation engine using Polars as backend. Given the characteristics of our data model, we chose to rely on a wide dataframe, where the variables contain the time dimension. This means:
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────┬───────────────┐
│ name ┆ var1_20231229 │
│ ---  ┆ ---           │
│ str  ┆ f64           │
╞══════╪═══════════════╡
│ VW   ┆ 0.5           │
│ BMW  ┆ 4.0           │
└──────┴───────────────┘


This model works perfectly fine with yearly, quarterly and even monthly data. However, when we introduce daily frequencies, thus adding columns and making the data even wider, the performance shrinks. This holds for a Pl.LazyFrame and setting Streaming = True. This is expected given the shape of the dataframe.
It is important to highlight the way we plan our queries: To take advantage of parallelisation, we group all the expressions that can be run together in the same with_columns context. Therefore, our queries would look like:
(df
 .with_columns(<first list of expressions>)
 .with_columns(<second list of expressions>)
 )


Where the second list of expressions may not use the columns in the original dataframe.
Is there a way to enhance the performance of this process? For example by extracting from each list of expressions only the columns that are required to calculate that list of expressions.

I don't think there's much advantage to splitting things up; since you're using a LazyFrame, the optimizer will go through and do that for you if it's necessary. The big change you should probably make, though, is to go from a wide df to a long one. Long is easier to optimize because you can look at smaller subsets of the data for row-wise operation (in theory you only need one row in memory at a time).
